# Putting a bean.method into a img src tag

Tags: image, jsp, methods, input, tags

I have a input value for my method which is

```
<h:inputText id="image_id" value="#{bean1.ID}" required="true" styleClass="input_text">
```

However, i need to place #{bean1.ID} in a image tag which is

```
<img src="/portal/view?image_id='#{bean1.ID}'" width="650" height="450" alt="Small image" />
```

and its not working. Does anyone have an idea on how you put the value into the image tag.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: What about src="#{bean.getImageURL}" and return the whole URL?

Comment: Also, if the EL does not provide a concatenation operator itself, surely the JSTL functions do have one

Comment: Oh i cant get the URL. This URL actually is being called from a servlet. and the bean1.ID is from a managed bean to run and get the information from the managed bean and display it out. That is why i want the bean1.ID value to be inserted into the path link. so that it can call the servlet and display the image out. Do you have any ideas how?

Comment: oh yeah. i tried using ur #{bean.getImageUrl}, however its still giving me the {...} template problem.